# Make jdk show the platform for which it was built for

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

Usecase
There are three platform specific JDKs, need to know which one is for ARM and download that specific jdk.

**Some background**

After the jdks are downloaded, I have tried the following command options and i see that the JDK that is being downloaded does not show which ARCHITECTURE it comes from. I would like to know whether there is an option from JDK SDK itself to see jdk + archi for which the jdk was being built for and not do at the time of download.

**Commands tried**

[apaa@iod-arm0000 jdk8]$ ./bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)

[apaa@iod-arm0000 jdk8]$ ./bin/java -showversion
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)

is there any file(inside JDK zip) that i can grep for to verify the ARCH for which it was built?

Comment: How about the `release` file?

Comment: Thank you @Holger 
i have greped the whole dir for ARM keyword, however, am unable to find something concrete.

Comment: Maybe, because you don’t have an “ARM” JDK, but an [AArch64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) JDK? As said, there should be a file named `release` directly in the JDK directory containing key value pairs, including a key `OS_ARCH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Holger

I was able to get the ARCHITECTURE from release for jdk 11.

```
jdk-11.0.16>cat release 
BUILD_TYPE="commercial"
IMPLEMENTOR="Oracle Corporation"
IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="18.9"
JAVA_VERSION="11.0.16"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2022-07-19"
MODULES="java.base java.compiler java.datatransfer java.xml java.prefs java.desktop java.instrument java.logging java.management java.security.sasl java.naming java.rmi java.management.rmi java.net.http java.scripting java.security.jgss java.transaction.xa java.sql java.sql.rowset java.xml.crypto java.se java.smartcardio jdk.accessibility jdk.internal.jvmstat jdk.attach jdk.charsets jdk.compiler jdk.crypto.ec jdk.crypto.cryptoki jdk.dynalink jdk.internal.ed jdk.editpad jdk.hotspot.agent jdk.httpserver jdk.internal.le jdk.internal.opt jdk.internal.vm.ci jdk.internal.vm.compiler jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management jdk.jartool jdk.javadoc jdk.jcmd jdk.management jdk.management.agent jdk.jconsole jdk.jdeps jdk.jdwp.agent jdk.jdi jdk.jfr jdk.jlink jdk.jshell jdk.jsobject jdk.jstatd jdk.localedata jdk.management.jfr jdk.naming.dns jdk.naming.ldap jdk.naming.rmi jdk.net jdk.pack jdk.rmic jdk.scripting.nashorn jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell jdk.sctp jdk.security.auth jdk.security.jgss jdk.unsupported jdk.unsupported.desktop jdk.xml.dom jdk.zipfs"
OS_ARCH="aarch64"
OS_NAME="Linux"
SOURCE=".:git:11e9b2b0a4eb open:git:f3b5596f5de6"
```